# sshpass/rsync fails when not redirecting stdout etc

Tags: bash, rsync, cygwin, cygwin-sshd

I am having a weird issue and I just can't seem to find the cause and a solution.

I am on win11/cygwin (sshpass 1.06,rsync 3.2.7)

I call:

```
/usr/bin/sshpass -p $sshpasswd /usr/bin/rsync --dry-run -azhvve ssh --mkpath --log-file=$sourcedir/$folder.log.txt --include-from=$sshsourcesfile --exclude=$sourcedir/* $sourcedir $sshtarget:$backupbasepath/$folder
```

Crosstesting the variables looks like the following and I assume this is just correct:

```
/usr/bin/sshpass -p xxxxxxxx /usr/bin/rsync --dry-run -azhvve ssh --mkpath --log-file=/F/2024_03_11-00_19_46_backup.log.txt --include-from=/F/2024_03_11-00_19_46_backup.sources.txt --exclude=/F/* /F root@192.168.0.100:/RAID/Software/MaintStick/2024_03_11-00_19_46_backup/
```

Above call ends up with an error:

```
2024/03/11 00:19:47 [560] rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
2024/03/11 00:19:47 [560] sent 0 bytes  received 0 bytes  total size 0
2024/03/11 00:19:47 [560] rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(231) [sender=3.2.7]
```

Now, if I add a redirection to the command, it works! I tried the following ones:

```
>/dev/null
>test.txt
| pv -lpes 2000
```

My question is: Why does the call fail without a redirection at the end?